# Construct a bijection given two injections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that if there exists an injection $f: A \to B$, then $|A| \leq |B|$. Then trivially, $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ both being injections imply that $|A| = |B|$. However, the definition of $|A| = |B|$ means that there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$. Is there any way to construct such a bijection from $f$ and $g$ or at least prove a bijection exists without using cardinality?

Comment: The proof of the Cantor-Bernstein (or Schröder-Bernstein) theorem gives a way to construct such a bijection. It works even for infinite sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a known and very important result.  With infinite sets, it is common that it is easy to find a pair of injections as you describe but not so easy to find an explicit bijection.

[Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)